# .htaccess Redirect Media File Requests to a Different Domain/Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, types, dns

Simply speaking, I want to substitute one file path for another in the URI, but only for certain file types.

I have a load of image files (PNG, GIF and JPG) on one server and a wordpress installation on another server. I can't put them all on the same server at the moment (for reasons too complicated to go into).

So, when I get a request for a PNG, GIF or JPG file on e.g.

http://www.server1.com/images1/image1.png

I want to be able to divert this request to the same image, but on server 2, potentially in a different top level subfolder e.g. "allimages" such as:

http://www.server2.com/allimages/images1/image1.png

Then, say divert:

http://www.server1.com/images2/image2.png

to

http://www.server2.com/allimages/images2/image2.png

I tried to make a start with .htaccess (on SERVER1) but haven't got very far. I put a .htaccess file in the root of Server 1, with these lines in:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.server2.com/allimages/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But I know this isn't correct. Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+(?:\.png|\.jpg|\.gif))$ http://www.server2.com/allimages/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Seems to work brilliantly! Thanks very much for your help! Great!